# Round fixed-point rational to narrower denominator

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, approximation, rational-numbers

I've got a (let's say nonnegative) rational number expressed as the ratio of two integers `a/b`, where `0 <= a < 2^m` and `0 < b < 2^n`. I'd like to round that to a smaller representation with only `p` bits in the denominator; that is, find the largest number `c/d` such that `c/d <= a/b`, where `0 < d < 2^p`.

Example: if `m=3, n=4, p=2`, I'd like to round `4/7` down to `1/2`, and `5/7` down to `2/3`.

My first impulse was to right-shift the denominator by `n-p`, adding 1 if a 1 was popped off, and right-shift the numerator by the same amount. That's guaranteed to produce a result less than `a/b`, but it doesn't guarantee optimality of the results. For instance, `3/1` rounds to `2/1`.

Ideally, I'd like to do this without division or modulus, but I suspect that might not be practical. `m`, `n`, and `p` may run into the hundreds, and this is going to be in an inner loop, so I'd like something as blazingly fast as possible.

Comment: Python's [`fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py#l206) has some useful notes about this in the source code. You could probably adapt that to whatever language you're working in.

Comment: @user2357112 Not bad! I'm not wild about the division within the loop, but I'll do some analysis to figure out the computational complexity... it might not be too bad. Thanks!